# Web Method not returning list?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webmethod

I have a .aspx page which I would like my WebMethod to return a List so I can call it from a jQuery ajax call and get a JSON type response... Here is my code but it just returns a blank page?

Any help would be great

```
    using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Services.Protocols;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

namespace Test.webservices.mainGrid
{
    public partial class staffTreeView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

        [WebMethod()]
        public static List<Staff> GetStaff()
        {
            try
            {
                List<Staff> staff = new List<Staff>();
                //  HttpCookie _userinfo = HttpContext.Current.Request.Cookies["userinfo"];
                string connectionstring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["TestProduction"].ConnectionString;
                SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(connectionstring);

                string sql = "sd_STAFFTREEVIEW";
                SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(sql, connection);

                command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlDataReader dr = command.ExecuteReader();

                while (dr.Read())
                {
                    staff.Add(new Staff()
                    {
                        id = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("id")),
                        NAME = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("NAME")),
                        PARENT = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("PARENT")),
                        VALUE = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("VALUE")),
                        VALUETYPE = dr.GetString(dr.GetOrdinal("VALUETYPE"))
                    });
                }
                dr.Close();
                return staff;
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw new System.Exception("No Data Returned:" + ex.Message);
            }

        }

        public class Staff
        {
            public string id { get; set; }
            public string NAME { get; set; }
            public string PARENT { get; set; }
            public string VALUE { get; set; }
            public string VALUETYPE { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

}

Comment: Did you verify staff count is nonzero?  Did you look at the JSON return value in browser debugger (firebug) to verify the JSON result is empty to ensure this is not a display/parsing problem?

Comment: On a side note, you should be closing your connection, or putting it in a "using" block.

Answer (score 0):

I would try changing the return type to a string and returning a json serialized string of the object.

Like this

```
JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();
string strJSON = js.Serialize(staff);
return strJSON;
```

Answer (score 0):

create a WCF service instead of a page !
and consider returning an Array instead of a generic list Staff[]

Answer (score 0):

Few things to check.

1. Do you need to enable the session : Services.WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)
2. Are you using the correct method name  ( check spelling). Better , could you post the code for ajax call ?
3. If you call the web method from somewhere else like code behind , is it giving you the correct result?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend that you use a WebAPI controller for this task, can be used in a web forms application, just wire up the routing in application_start

It will save you some pain and make your life easier

http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/creating-web-apis/using-web-api-with-aspnet-web-forms

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that your ajax call is not happening.

Provided you are sure that your list is not empty, make sure that you have set the dataType and contentType of your ajax request to json and "application/json" respectively.

If you are using a script manager control make sure Enablepagemethods is set to true.

finally you can try setting a break point in your error callback to find if there are any serialisation errors.if so, you can try to serialise the LIST to JSON using JavaScriptSerializer and return the result as String